# Format XML containing List for Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have some data which I need to bring from an XML file to a PostgreSQL database through a C# application I am currently working on.

The problem I face now is that I need to add some kind of list to the XML now. Currently it looks something like this:

```
<itemOne>stuff</itemOne>
<itemTwo>otherStuff</itemTwo>
<listOfItems>
    <listItem>
        <partOne>123</partOne>
        <partTwo>abc</partTwo>
    </listItem>
    <listItem>
        <partOne>123</partOne>
        <partTwo>abc</partTwo>
    </listItem>
</listOfItems>
```

So I found quite some threads which handle the topic of how to deserialize lists. But all of them start by saying that the proposed XML should be modified. As I have all the freedom that I could wish for in that regard, I'd like to first create an optimal XML format at first.

Well, and afterwards deserialize it. So if there is any format for lists which is automatically processed by XmlSerializer.Deserialize() it would be amazing.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Is this XML format (especially the list) fine for deserialization using XmlSerializer?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: Well, I did try and it didn't work. I then did read similar questions here on SO which state that the better the format, the easier/cleaner the deserialization is (paraphrasing here)

Comment: @JacobS not quite - `XmlSerializer`  wants a single root element - you don't have that at the moment; in my answer I've assumed there is actually a parent `<yourRootName>`. What you have is an xml **fragment** - not an xml node/document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data will already be processed automatically by `XmlSerializer`, as long as the class is shaped to match. For example:

```
[XmlRoot("yourRootName")]
public class Foo {
    [XmlElement("itemOne")] public string A {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("itemTwo")] public string B {get;set;}

    [XmlArray("listOfItems")]
    [XmlArrayItem("listItem")]
    public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}
public class Bar {
    [XmlElement("partOne")] public int C {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("partTwo")] public string D {get;set;}
}
```

Of course, if it was me I'd be tempted to be terse, with:

```
<betterName foo="stuff" blab="otherStuff">
     <nameMe a="123" b="abc"/>
     <nameMe a="456" b="def"/>
</betterName>
```

which just requires some minimal changes:

```
[XmlRoot("betterName")]
public class Foo {
    [XmlAttribute("foo")] public string A {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("bar")] public string B {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("nameMe")]
    public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}
public class Bar {
    [XmlAttribute("a")] public int C {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("b")] public string D {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works like a charm! I found the errors I had in the differences of my version to your first version and will try to go for the cleaner/shorter second version of yours when I'll understand everything.